# TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly

Tags: python, tensorflow, ray

I tried to install [Ray](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/), but it gave an error:

```
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your protos, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the protobuf package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).
```

I tried to solve the problem and downgraded *protobuf*:

```
Name: protobuf
Version: 3.20.0
Summary: Protocol Buffers
Home-page: https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/
Author:
Author-email:
License: BSD-3-Clause
Location: d:\opencv\lib\site-packages
Requires:
Required-by: ray, tensorboard, tensorflow
```

But still the problem persists in Ray, [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow), and [Keras](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keras). My application isn't working any more. How can I fix it?

Comment: maybe try lower version of protobuf - ie. `3.19`, `3.18`

Comment: I down grade `protobuf` from `4.21.1` to `3.20.1`. https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10051

Comment: For future readers, I downgraded to `3.20.0` which solved my problem, `3.21.1` wasn't working for me (I got the same error).

Answer (score 247):

Sometimes the [protobuf](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/) package might be installed without your involvement. For this, you have two solutions to apply. Try one of the below solutions and it should work.

### Solution 1:

You can downgrade the [protobuf](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/) plugin,

```
pip install protobuf==3.20.*
```

Or you can add it to the `requirements.txt` file as the last package. Because this will override the previously installed [protobuf](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/) package.

```
...
protobuf==3.20.*
```

### Solution 2:

You can set the following environment variable.

```
export PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python
```

according to the error description, this might impact your program performance.

> but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower

---

References:

- [TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly](https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/typeerror-descriptors-cannot-not-be-created-directly/25639)
- [[Python] Release 4.21.0 broke multiple Google Cloud client libraries ("TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.")](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10051)

Comment: After following the solution 01 and solution 02, both result in my program running ~5 times slower. I also tried to rebuild the environment and it still runs as slow. Mi guess is that something is forcing `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python` even when using solution 01, but I have no way to check it. Is it happening to anybody else? How could I go back to the original state?

Comment: You're correct @Guillem , Solution 02 might impact your program performance and they've mentioned it in the error description as well. But the Solution 01 should work

Comment: The thing is that Solution 01 is also impacting performance. I even tried to reinstall conda but the code won't run as fast as before.

Comment: @Guillem it cannot be, I did the same and I couldn't identify any performance issue in my program. Sorry about that.

Comment: And what happens when the older version is no longer supported??

Comment: I had this problem with aws sagemaker and solution 1 worked for me.

Answer (score 32):

**Solution 1:** Downgrade Protobuf

This library has recently released a new version, which causes an error. Use this command in the terminal to downgrade, which should resolve the problem:

```
pip install --upgrade "protobuf<=3.20.1"
```

Or force a reinstallation of an older version:

```
pip install 'protobuf<=3.20.1' --force-reinstall
```

**Solution 2:** Update TensorFlow to the latest version

TensorFlow 2.9.1 was released on 23 May 2022. It can be updated like so:

```
pip install tensorflow==2.9.1
```

Always use the latest version of TensorFlow.

Comment: actually for tensorflow 2.9.1, you should have protobuf < 3.20: https://github.com/chxin66/tensorflow/commit/c2a8a98b764ac8f0352cac0a438007c899af8f96#diff-f526feeafa1000c4773410bdc5417c4022cb2c7b686ae658b629beb541ae9112L90

Comment: solution 1 worked for me

Comment: force reinstall did the trick for me

Answer (score 13):

In my case I did not have `protobuf` explicitly in my `requirements.txt` file, but I did have a related dependency which was apparently problematic:

`googleapis-common-protos==1.6.0  # Depends on protobuf`

***Removing*** this allowed the subsequent `pip install -e .` (assuming `setup.py` is present) to go with whatever `google-api-core==1.13.0` had for dependencies. That resulted in the installation of `googleapis-common-protos==1.56.2` and resolved the error.

Answer (score 13):

Even I came across the same error.

I solved it by installing protobuf:

```
pip install protobuf==3.20.
```

[image: Screen Snippet]

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/73947066/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

The command

```
pip install protobuf==3.20.3 --upgrade
```

Worked for me. All other versions mentioned in the answers did not solve the problem.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, I was able to upgrade to `wandb==0.12.17`, and everything seems to be working.

Old (not working):

```
  - pip:
      - wandb==0.10.21
```

New (working):

```
  - pip:
      - wandb==0.12.17
```

Answer (score 4):

Descriptors cannot not be created directly:

1. We need to downgrade the protobuf package from 4.21.2 to 3.20.1.
2. Go to setting → *Project* → *Python Interpreter* → install protobuf 3.20.1 (specify version)

Answer (score 4):

The following worked for me in [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow) 2.8:

```
pip install protobuf==3.20.*
```

Answer (score 1):

I found the same problem, but I followed the instructions on this web page:

*[Python Packaging User Guide](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/)* ([on GitHub](https://github.com/pypa/packaging.python.org))

### Steps

#### Requirements / prerequisites:

1. sphinx 4.3.1
2. sphinx-autobuild 0.7.1
3. sphinx-inline-tabs 2021.4.11b9
4. python-docs-theme 2021.5
5. sphinx-copybutton 0.4.0
6. Output of `python -V`:

   > Python 3.8.10
7. Output of `protoc.exe --version`:

   > libprotoc 3.21.0-rc2

#### Installation:

1. `pip install git+https://github.com/pypa/pypa-docs-theme.git#egg=pypa-docs-theme`
2. Compile libraries
3. Copy the compiled library from F:\temp\Python\protoc\packaging.python.org\protobuf\Debug to F:\temp\Python\protoc\packaging.python.org\protobuf\src

**Output:**

```
installing library code to build\bdist.win-amd64\egg
running install_lib
running build_py
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google
copying google\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google
creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\any_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\api_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\descriptor.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\descriptor_database.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\descriptor_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\descriptor_pool.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\duration_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\empty_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\field_mask_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\json_format.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\message.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\message_factory.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\proto_builder.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\reflection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\service.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\service_reflection.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\source_context_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\struct_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\symbol_database.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\text_encoding.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\text_format.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\timestamp_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\type_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\unknown_fields.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\wrappers_pb2.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf
copying google\protobuf\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8\google\protobuf

...
testTimestampSerializeAndParse (google.protobuf.internal.well_known_types_test.TimeUtilTest) ... ok
testTimezoneAwareDatetimeConversionLA (google.protobuf.internal.well_known_types_test.TimeUtilTest)
testTimezoneAwareDatetimeConversionLA([1969, 12, 31, 18], datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(days=-1, seconds=57600), 'US/Pacific')) ... ok
testTimezoneAwareDatetimeConversionLondon (google.protobuf.internal.well_known_types_test.TimeUtilTest)
testTimezoneAwareDatetimeConversionLondon([1970, 1, 1, 2], datetime.timezone.utc) ... ok
testTimezoneAwareDatetimeConversionTokyo (google.protobuf.internal.well_known_types_test.TimeUtilTest)
testTimezoneAwareDatetimeConversionTokyo([1970, 1, 1, 11], datetime.timezone(datetime.timedelta(seconds=32400), 'Japan')) ... ok
testTimezoneNaiveDatetimeConversion (google.protobuf.internal.well_known_types_test.TimeUtilTest) ... ok
testByteSizeFunctions (google.protobuf.internal.wire_format_test.WireFormatTest) ... ok
testPackTag (google.protobuf.internal.wire_format_test.WireFormatTest) ... ok
testUnpackTag (google.protobuf.internal.wire_format_test.WireFormatTest) ... ok
testZigZagDecode (google.protobuf.internal.wire_format_test.WireFormatTest) ... ok
testZigZagEncode (google.protobuf.internal.wire_format_test.WireFormatTest) ... ok
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue after upgrading [Google Cloud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Google_Cloud_Platform) logging.

I solved it upgrading *google-cloud-audit-log*:

```
pip install google-cloud-audit-log==0.2.4
```

Working versions:

```
pip freeze | grep google

google-api-core==2.10.2
google-api-python-client==2.57.0
google-auth==2.10.0
google-auth-httplib2==0.1.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.5.2
google-cloud-appengine-logging==1.1.6
google-cloud-audit-log==0.2.4
google-cloud-core==2.3.2
google-cloud-logging==3.2.5
google-cloud-storage==2.5.0
google-crc32c==1.1.2
google-resumable-media==2.4.0
googleapis-common-protos==1.56.4
grpc-google-iam-v1==0.12.4
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using TensorFlow 1.15.5 and Python 3.7.9.

These particular versions helped for me:

wandb                    0.12.17 
protobuf                 3.15.0

You can use:

```
pip install wandb==0.12.17

pip uninstall protobuf

pip install protobuf==3.15.0
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing your case, it really helped (^_^).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. In my case, I simply verified my Python interpreter to be sure [Protocol Buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) (3.20.3) is installed into the interpreter, which was not the case, although it was installed on the virtual environment created for the project.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve a similar problem by uninstalling [Protocol Buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) using pip and then installing an older version (3.20.1) of the package using [Conda](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conda_(package_manager)).

```
pip uninstall protobuf
conda install 'protobuf=3.20.1'
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with streamlit.

OLD-> streamlit==1.19.0

I updated the version of streamlit using
`pip install streamlit --upgrade` and it worked.

New -> streamlit==1.23.1

Answer (score 0):

I had a very simple solution to this exact problem when downgrading [Protocol Buffers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_Buffers) didn’t work (and I didn’t want to risk reducing program performance). I encountered this problem when running a notebook in Visual Studio Code.

My solution was to open Visual Studio Code as an administrator via CMD.

Answer (score 0):

What did it for me was updating [TensorFlow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TensorFlow) from version 2.5.0 to 2.12.

Answer (score 0):

I recently saw this same error in my code. In my case there was also a stack trace that implicated `pychromecast`. So, for me, the fix was just an update of the `pychromecast` package. It is just a reminder that the fix may not necessarily be a downgrade of some package.