# How to downgrade protobuf

Tags: python, protocol-buffers

By accident I updated `protobuf` on my Ubuntu vps. Now some very essential Python scripts don't work anymore. Speed isn't really important. I got two solutions:

```
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly.
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0.
If you cannot immediately regenerate your `protos`, some other possible workarounds are:
 1. Downgrade the `protobuf` package to 3.20.x or lower.
 2. Set `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python` (but this will use pure-Python parsing and will be much slower).
```

Downgrade the `protobuf` package, not sure it that's the way forward

or `Set PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python` - but where do I set this. In the python script?

Answer (score 54):

#### Downgrade protobuf using pip

```
pip install protobuf==3.20.*
```

Note: the `*` above is not to be taken literally, it's called a "wildcard". You put your own number in there as needed, as in `3.20.1`, `3.20.5`, etc.

This is similar to [TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441758/typeerror-descriptors-cannot-not-be-created-directly)

Comment: This is the error that pops up `no matches found: protobuf==3.20.*`

Comment: You can run “pip install --upgrade pip” to install and use the new version of pip. Check if this helps

Comment: I actually used the wildcard before reading the Note, and it worked XD

Comment: Seems, wildcard form was fixed: ` pip install protobuf==3.20.* ... Using cached protobuf-3.20.3-cp310...`

Answer (score 1):

See [Changes made in May, 2022](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/news/2022-05-06) for background.

I'd discourage using `PROTOCOL_BUFFERS_PYTHON_IMPLEMENTATION=python` as your solution. But if you want to use it, you would need to set this environment variable (and possibly `export` it too?) in the environment where you're running code that uses the generated sources (both client and server if applicable).

See this [thread](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10051) about the above change.

Here's the `protobuf` [releases](https://pypi.org/project/protobuf/#history).

If you don't want to recompile your protos, you may want to try moving to `3.20.1` but realize this is the end of the line and you're delaying the inevitable...

If you're willing to recompile (and test) your protos, you should consider moving to `4.20.x`.