# ContextualVersionConflict, when attempting to pip install google-cloud-bigquery on AWS SageMaker

Tags: python, google-bigquery, pip, amazon-sagemaker

pip install google-cloud-bigquery

```
Requirement already satisfied: pyasn1<0.5.0,>=0.4.6 in /home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from pyasn1-modules>=0.2.1->google-auth<3.0dev,>=1.25.0->google-api-core[grpc]!=2.0.*,!=2.1.*,!=2.2.*,!=2.3.0,<3.0.0dev,>=1.31.5->google-cloud-bigquery) (0.4.8)
Installing collected packages: pyasn1-modules, protobuf, grpcio, google-crc32c, cachetools, proto-plus, googleapis-common-protos, google-resumable-media, google-auth, grpcio-status, google-api-core, google-cloud-core, google-cloud-bigquery-storage, google-cloud-bigquery
  Attempting uninstall: protobuf
    Found existing installation: protobuf 3.19.1
    Uninstalling protobuf-3.19.1:
      Successfully uninstalled protobuf-3.19.1
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
sagemaker 2.117.0 requires protobuf<4.0,>=3.1, but you have protobuf 4.21.9 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed cachetools-5.2.0 google-api-core-2.10.2 google-auth-2.14.1 google-cloud-bigquery-3.4.0 google-cloud-bigquery-storage-2.16.2 google-cloud-core-2.3.2 google-crc32c-1.5.0 google-resumable-media-2.4.0 googleapis-common-protos-1.57.0 grpcio-1.51.0 grpcio-status-1.51.0 proto-plus-1.22.1 protobuf-4.21.9 pyasn1-modules-0.2.8
WARNING: You are using pip version 22.0.4; however, version 22.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Note: you may need to restart the kernel to use updated packages.


ContextualVersionConflict: (protobuf 3.19.1 (/home/ec2-user/anaconda3/envs/python3/lib/python3.8/site-packages), Requirement.parse('protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5'), {'google-cloud-bigquery-storage'})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try running `pip install -U protobuf~=3.20.0` and then `pip install google-cloud-bigquery`.

Protobuf 4.x versions have some incompatibilities with other libraries.

Ref: [How to downgrade protobuf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72899948/how-to-downgrade-protobuf)