# ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. Dataflow python custom template

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow

When I create a custom dataflow template Ppython), yesterday the template worked fine but today when I execute the template it returns an error and I can't fix it.

```
TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly
If this call came from a _pb2.py file, your generated code is out of date and must be regenerated with protoc >= 3.19.0. (I changed version in requirements.txt but nothigs works). 
And then appear this text.
google-cloud-vision 1.0.0 requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core 2.10.0 which is incompatible
google-cloud-videointelligence 1.16.1 requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core 2.10.0 which is incompatible
google-cloud-spanner 1.19.1 requires google-api-core[grpc,grpcgcp]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core 2.10.0 which is incompatible
google-cloud-recommendations-ai 0.2.0 requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.22.2, but you have google-api-core 2.10.0 which is incompatible
google-cloud-language 1.3.0 requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core 2.10.0 which is incompatible
google-cloud-datastore 1.15.3 requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core 2.10.0 which is incompatible
google-cloud-core 1.7.2 requires google-api-core<2.0.0dev,>=1.21.0, but you have google-api-core 2.10.0 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-bigtable 1.7.0 requires google-api-core[grpc]<2.0.0dev,>=1.14.0, but you have google-api-core 2.10.0 which is incompatible
apache-beam 2.36.0 requires protobuf<4,>=3.12.2, but you have protobuf 4.21.5 which is incompatible.
```

Comment: please check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441758/typeerror-descriptors-cannot-not-be-created-directly/, it might help you to resolve your issue

Comment: Hi, thaks for response. I resolved the issue changing the version of protobuf in requiremetns.txt and changes other dependencies.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar issue. After looking at [TypeError: Descriptors cannot not be created directly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441758/typeerror-descriptors-cannot-not-be-created-directly/) I was able to resolve it by adding the line
`protobuf==3.20.1` to the end of my `requirements.txt` file, that caused an override to the `protobuf` pip installation to this specific version, as some other package was upgrading it.

You can also check if your version of `protobuf` is compatible. If not, please change it.

Comment: thanks for response! In my case it wasn't necessary to add protobuf==3.20.1 at the end of the file but it was necessary to change the version.

Comment: @turqo92 yes, that's true. i've updated my answer to explicitly state that, even though i believe that was implied. if it helped you, please mark the answer as accepted, it helps the community.