# import mysql.connector not working on Google Cloud Functions

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, mysql-connector

I am attempting to run my python script in google cloud functions to access it via an HTTP request for automation purposes. The problem I am having is when deploying the following:

```
from datetime import datetime, date, timedelta
import time
import mysql.connector
import requests
from dotty_dict import dotty
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
from mysql.connector import Error
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from fractions import Fraction
```

I get the following error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '_version'"`

I then change my import to only import MySQL as standalone like the following:

```
import time
import mysql
import requests
from dotty_dict import dotty
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import smtplib
from email.message import EmailMessage
from fractions import Fraction
```

I then get an AttributeError naturally: `AttributeError: module 'mysql' has no attribute 'connector'"`

My connection within my function looks like this: `connection = mysql.connector.connect`

I have got requirements.txt file which contains the following:

```
fake_useragent==1.1.1
mysql_connector_repackaged==0.3.1
numpy==1.23.5
requests==2.28.1
```

Doing some general research it was recommended to try upgrade the MySQL package - I proceeded to upgrade the MySQL package via the cloud shell with the normal pip command: `pip install mysql-connector-python --upgrade`

I get the following issue:

```
ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
grpcio-status 1.51.1 requires protobuf>=4.21.6, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
googleapis-common-protos 1.57.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-vision 3.1.4 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-videointelligence 2.8.3 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-translate 3.8.4 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-spanner 3.24.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-logging 3.3.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-language 2.6.1 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-datastore 2.11.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-bigquery 3.4.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-bigquery-storage 2.16.2 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-cloud-appengine-logging 1.1.6 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
google-api-core 2.11.0 requires protobuf!=3.20.0,!=3.20.1,!=4.21.0,!=4.21.1,!=4.21.2,!=4.21.3,!=4.21.4,!=4.21.5,<5.0.0dev,>=3.19.5, but you have protobuf 3.20.1 which is incompatible.
```

I then attempted to upgrade protobuf and I received this error:

```
mysql-connector-python 8.0.31 requires protobuf<=3.20.1,>=3.11.0, but you have protobuf 4.21.11 which is incompatible.
Successfully installed protobuf-4.21.11
```

Any ideas on what I need to do to get this working?

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441758), which states that

> Sometimes the [protobuf](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/issues/10051) package might be installed without your involvement.

To resolve this issue, try to downgrade the protobuf plugin by using the command

`pip install protobuf==3.20.*`

Or try to add it in the `requirements.txt` which will overwrite the existing protobuf package.

In the above mentioned [Stackoverflow Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441758) there are many alternate solutions as well you can refer to them which might be useful.

Meanwhile check other packages installed on your Google cloud function should be compatible with the MySQL connector Package. You can also refer to these [Github Link](https://github.com/apple/turicreate/issues/3383#issuecomment-1010006358) and [Documentation](https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/python-error-pips-dependency-resolver-does-not-currently-take) which may help you.