# What alternative deployment options are there for Azure Functions that remove build automation with Oryx?

Tags: python, azure, azure-functions, azure-web-app-service

I am trying to deploy an Azure Function to a vnet attached Azure App Service and am receiving the following error:

```
Error: System.AggregateException: Http request to retrieve the SDKs available to download from 'https://oryx-cdn.microsoft.io' failed. Please ensure that your network configuration allows traffic to required Oryx dependencies, as documented in 'https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/main/doc/hosts/appservice.md#network-dependencies'
```

The error message is clear and provides a good link to documentation that explains what needs to change in my network environment to enable the App Service to reach out to the internet to pull the required Oryx dependencies.

Are there any other options for me to deploy my Function App that eliminate the requirement to change my networking configuration, or is enabling Oryx build automation the only way I will be able to deploy my Function App?

Answer (score 0):

> Are there any other options for me to deploy my Function App that eliminate the requirement to change my networking configuration.

Unfortunately, Its a known limitation on Azure App Service Linux for Oryx. In order to resolve this error, Refer this [**Blog**](https://azureossd.github.io/2023/04/17/troubleshooting-python-deployments-on-appservice-linux/):-

*- Make sure the [**below**](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/main/doc/configuration.md) App settings are present in your Web app.*

*- And the Oryx CDN endpoint is whitelisted as given [**here**](https://github.com/microsoft/Oryx/blob/main/doc/hosts/appservice.md#network-dependencies)*

One alternative is to deploy your Function app in Dedicated Premium Plan or App Service plan.

[image]

And deploy the **Function app with any of the options below which has Oryx enabled by default**:-

1. Zip Deploy
2. Azure DevOps
3. Github Actions
4. Bitbucket
5. Local Git as mentioned in the Blog above.

**Make sure this setting *SCM_DO_BUILD_DURING_DEPLOYMENT = true* is present.**

***Azure DevOps Pipeline to deploy Function trigger:-***

All Functions dependency got installed successfully and deployment is successful in Pipeline:-

[image]

**Refer my [SO thread answer1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76276661/unable-to-explain-why-my-python-based-azure-function-is-not-appearing-when-using/76277867#76277867) to deploy Python Function with Github Actions and [SO thread answer2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76564629/cannot-import-protobuf-builder-when-deploying-azure-function/76570070#76570070) to deploy the Python Function with Azure Devops.**