# pip dependency conflict_ cannot install tweetnlp

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, nlp, emotion

I tried to install `tweetnlp` package from [here](https://pypi.org/project/tweetnlp/) to analyze emotions of some social media text. However, I get the following error when I run `pip install tweetnlp`:

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> tensorflow 2.11.0 requires protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2, but you have protobuf 4.23.3 which is incompatible.
> tensorboard 2.11.2 requires protobuf<4,>=3.9.2, but you have protobuf 4.23.3 which is incompatible.

I used a solution from [a similar post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72441758/typeerror-descriptors-cannot-not-be-created-directly) (using `pip install protobuf==3.20.*` command), but I got the following error:

> ERROR: pip's dependency resolver does not currently take into account all the packages that are installed. This behaviour is the source of the following dependency conflicts.
> tensorboardx 2.6.1 requires protobuf>=4.22.3, but you have protobuf 3.20.3 which is incompatible.
> tensorflow 2.11.0 requires protobuf<3.20,>=3.9.2, but you have protobuf 3.20.3 which is incompatible.

What can I try next?

Answer (score 0):

**Virtual environments allow you to have multiple versions of the same package/module (of course, each in its own virtual environment).** In fact, each of your applications, consisting of possibly multiple scripts, should run from its own virtual environment. This not only allows your applications to have different versions of the same module, each virtual environment neatly encapsulates an application's module requirements.

1. Create a virtual environment in some directory. See [this documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html).
2. Activate the virtual environment and install `tweetnlp` and any other modules you need for execution. To activate a virtual environment, execute the command `source activate` from the virtual environment's *bin* directory (Linux) or the command `activate` from the virtual environment's *Scripts* directory (Windows). After installing your modules you can deactivate the virtual environment with the `deactivate` command.
3. Make your script's first line the *shebang* `#!full-path-to-python3` where *full-path-to-python3* is the full path to the Python 3 interpreter that was installed in your virtual environment. `python3` will either be in the virtual environment's *bin* or *Scripts* directory according to the platform. This allows you to run your script without having to first explicitly re-activate your virtual environment.